# navigation bar link to companion site

Tags: php

I have just set up 2 sites `www.daypackrambler.co.uk` and `www.daypackranger.co.uk` and am trying to create navigation menu bar links between them. The php array menu bar links for pages within each site work fine but the bar links between the 2 sites don't work. I thought it may be because I didn't have the full required path for the links. But having confirmed the correct host server path (both sites are on the same server) still no joy.

Using the daypackranger site as an example my navigation bar link coding is

```
<?php $pages = array('index.php' => 'Home', 'about.php' => 'About', 'countryskills.php' => 'Country Skills', 'habitatsandwildlife.php' => 'Habitats and Wildlife',

'../home/daypack1/daypackrambler.co.uk/index.php' => 'Daypack<br /> Rambler',

'links.php' => 'Links', 'contact.php' => 'Contact',) ;
$currentPage = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ; ?>
```

the problem code is the separate line in the middle. I have tried a few variations without success. A href version can't be used as the " elements will create an error.

The code is part of a sidebar template as a "master" for the whole site rather than standard navigation buttons on each individual page (that can use a standard external coding link) - as the site grows it will become quite onerous to update each individual page with new navigation links.The error notification was

```
Not Found

The requested URL /href=http://www.daypackrambler.co.uk/index.php/ was not found on this server.
```

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

### Apache/2.2.26 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.26 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at www.daypackranger.co.uk Port 80

The appears to be reading the correct site address but for some reason not seeing it.

As a Stackoveflow newby I hope this lengthy question provides enough detail of what my problem is and exactly what it is I am trying to do. ie as well as the usually site page links I want 1 nav button for a separate companion site.

Comment: Have you tried using: `'http://www.daypackrambler.co.uk' => 'Daypack Rambler'`?

Comment: thanks for that, worked a treat so obvious now I've seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, you're not actually providing the link, but rather the file location (which is not accessible through a browser).

What you want to do is use

```
'http://www.daypackrambler.co.uk' => 'Daypack<br /> Rambler',
```

instead of

```
'../home/daypack1/daypackrambler.co.uk/index.php' => 'Daypack<br /> Rambler',
```

What you wrote is the Unix file location. Links cannot point to it. A link should point to the URL that's visible to the outside world ;)

Hope that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks worked a treat and nice to know why the path didn't work. I didn't think to try the address without the "href". Seems so obvious now.